# A square lattice in a homogeneous magnetic field B: How would it be the direction of the magnetic potential $A$ in the given picture?

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory, network

I have an infinite square lattice that is placed in a homogenous magnetic field $B$ with vector potential $A$.

[image]

**My Question**

Can someone please explain/illustrate how it would be the direction and magnitude of $A$ on each edge of the lattice above?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique answer as it depends on your gauge choice.  A simple and popular choice is to make the $A_x=0$ on the horizonal links and $A_y$ equal to a constant times $n$ on the vertical links where $na$ is the $x$ coordinate.  The hopping factor is $U=1$ on the horintal links and then $U_y=\exp{i a A_y}$ on the vertical lins.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_butterfly) is a link for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, in this particular gauge choice, can we consider the system periodic and specify a unit cell that the whole system can be obtained by repeating the unit cell? @mikestone

Comment: You only get a periodic unit cell when the flux through a single plaquette is a rational function of the flux quantum $\Phi_0=2\pi \hbar/e$  If the flux per plaquette  is $(p/q) \Phi_0$ then the unit cell has $q$ plquettes. All this is in Hofstadter's original paper  or In the TKN$^2$ article

Comment: I have other questions (sorry my major is not solid state physics): is $n$ in your answer a natural (nonzero) number? Then, is my new figure (added to the text) correct? what would be the hopping factor on the next vertical edges above? Also, since the lattice is infinite and symmetric, what is the hopping factor for the vertical edges on the left-hand side of the index $N=1$? @mikestone

Comment: And one more important question, if the red block is my unit cell containing $N$ vertices, for which free ends of the unit cell, the Floquet-Bloch decomposition apply?  @mikestone

Comment: You need to set up Harper's equation. I think that the Wiki page I linked to explains this.  Certainly the original Hofstadter paper explain in much greater detail than I can go into.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again; may I ask you to comment on my latest question which is related to this? @mikestone

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything to add to my other comments. YOu need to read and work through the recommnded papers. Then it it will all be obvious.